# How to dynamically populate a reference-type array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, memory

In order to create an array in Java, one must allocate space for it in memory. For example, in order to create an array of primitive ints, I need to:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
```

If I want to then populate this array, I can easily do so:

```
arr[1] = 5;
arr[2] = 10;
// etc.
```

My question is, what if I want to create an array of, let's say, objects of class Card. Each I want to initialize with values in a programmatic way. For example, let's say I want to create a Deck of cards, as such:

```
Card[][] deck;

for(int i = DIAMONDS; i <= SPADES; ++i) {
   for(int i = ACE; i <= KING; ++i) {
        deck[i][j] = new Card(i, j);
   }
}
```

Of course, this code will throw a `NullPointerException`. So the solution is to allocate memory for the array in advance:

```
Card[][] deck = new Card[SPADES][KING];
```

Now the code will work. But as far as I understand, this is a huge waste of memory: There will be space for 52 Card objects in memory with default values for the array, and then another 52 Card objects created in the two for loops.

What is the way to handle this in Java?

Comment: First off: there are no multidimensional arrays in Java, just arrays of arrays. Second, if we have a referenced-type array, only the reference (i.e. 64 bit) are stored in the array, not the objejct. In total, we will have 1 (outer array) + 4 (inner arrays) + 52 (cards) = 57 arrays created. Probably some more if each cards allocates some additional objects (e.g. `String`s).

Comment: @Turing85 `There are no multidimensional arrays in Java, just arrays of arrays`  True. but The Java Language Specification explains that they are arrays of arrays one time.  Then the spec goes on in numerous places to use the term `multidimensional array(s)`.  So using that term is acceptable.  Of course, I prefer, `1D and 2D`, etc.  But I'm not certain why this was brought up since the OP never mentioned it.

Comment: @WJS beacuse OP seems to be concerned about memory. If we use multidimensional arrays (in a C-sense), they do bear only a minimal, additional overhead if done right, and the memory can be consecutive. In Java, we create more arrays, and they might not be consecutive in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But as far as I understand, this is a huge waste of memory: There will be space for 52 Card objects in memory with default values for the array, and then another 52 Card objects created in the two for loops.

No, it's not. When you create an array of objects like this:

```java
Card[][] deck = new Card[SPADES][KING];
```

Java is not creating space for objects, but it's creating **space for references**, which you'll initialize in your loops later, so  you're not allocating memory twice.